# Twitter API Upload Media: Code 32: Could not authenticate you

Tags: c#, twitter, restsharp

I trying to upload an image with twitter API but I keep getting error 32

```
({"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}).
```

I manage to make it work with postman i didnt know why I miss with RestSharp?

```
public async Task UploadImageAsync()
{
    var imagePath = @"C:\myImagePath.png";
    byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

    _restClientUpload.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(customer_key, customer_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret);
    var path = $"media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image";
    var request = new RestRequest(path, Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    request.AddFileBytes("media", imageArray, "image/png");
    var response = await _restClientUpload.ExecuteAsync(request);

    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

my cURL from postman here =>

```
  curl --location --request POST 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image' \
--header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="key",oauth_token="key",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1632574953",oauth_nonce="key",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="key%3D"' \
--header 'Cookie: personalization_id="v1_13irasMvxdwwHKs9IM70kQ=="; guest_id=v1%3A163249534337658048; lang=en' \
--form 'media=@"/C:/Users/albin/Downloads/4O3ikRBUJAM3BinKmhQDpX_eL2HLXUzUKfnyn8CxgW8.png"'
```

Comment: I'm also stuck, been looking for a solution for hours now. This is ridiculous, even Twitter dev forum is stuck mostly because of this: > "Because the method uses multipart POST, OAuth is handled differently.
> POST or query string parameters are not used when calculating an OAuth
> signature basestring or signature. Only the oauth_* parameters are
> used." source: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload I get same error like you, why couldn't they just say specifically what the problem is in the API response. I don't know what am